# JAX odeint with generalised functions

Tags: python, ode, jax, automatic-differentiation

How does one use JAX `odeint` to generate differentiable numerical solutions to ODEs involving generalised functions?

The following is a simple example, where a C2 differentiable numerical solution to the following IVP is the goal.

[image]

One possible implementation using `JAX` is

```
import jax as jx
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.experimental.ode import odeint

# Enable double precision
jx.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)

def calc_dy(y,x):
    dy = 1.0-y*y
    return 1.0/jnp.abs(dy)

def calc_y1(y0):
   x_grid = jnp.linspace(0.0,1.0,2**1)
   y_grid = odeint(calc_dy,y0,x_grid)
   return y_grid[-1]

calc_dy1 = jx.grad(calc_y1)

calc_res = lambda y0 : 1.0/calc_dy1(y0)
calc_dres = jx.grad(calc_res)

y0 = jnp.array(0.0)

print(f'res  = {calc_res(y0)}')
# res  = -1.3472950405756983

print(f"dres = {calc_dres(y0)}")
# dres = nan
```

The defined residual function, `res`, can be used for a shooting method which tries to find the critical initial condition that results in the slope singularity being located at x = 1.0. However, for initial values above the critical value, `dres` (a recursive use of `jx.grad`) returns `nan` which prevents the use of a gradient-based solver.

Is there a way to make `dres` return values for any initial value `y0`?

Comment: You are probably dividing by zero in either `calc_y2` or `calc_res`. Either reformulate your problem or add a small regularization parameter to your denominators.

Comment: This doesn't happen in the forward pass, which can be tested by running the kernel of `calc_y1` with a dense abscissa, such as `x_grid = jnp.linspace(0.0,1.0,2**10)`. The zero division is happening in the back-propagation call to `custom_vjp`. The underlying question is why does the back pass divide by zero, when the forward pass avoids it.

Comment: @Jim Raynor I didn't go deeper with this. I implemented my own linearly implicit integrator with a custom adaptive step algorithm that avoided the PID accept/reject, and solved the outer optimisation problem using an inverse map rather than a gradient-based approach

Comment: I suspect the issue lies in the use of the implicit function theorem with JAX's odeint